# RarFile Python Module

Tags: python, python-3.x, zip, rar

I am trying to make a simple bruteforcer for rar files. My code is...

```
import rarfile

file = input("Password List Directory: ")
rarFile = input("Rar File: ")

passwordList = open(file,"r")


for i in passwordList:

    try :
        rarfile.read(rarFile, psw=i)
        print('[+] Password Found: '+i)

    except Exception as e:
        print('[-] '+i+' is not a password ')

passwordList.close()
```

I think this has to do with my use of the module, because when I input a password list that I am 10000% sure contains the password to the rarFile, it prints the exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The real problem here is that you are catching all exceptions, not just the one you want. So use `except rarfile.PasswordRequired:`  That will show you that the error is not a missing password. Instead there is no function `read` in the rarfile module.

Have a look at some [Documentation](https://rarfile.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#module-rarfile). Rar encryption is per file, not per archive.

You need to create a  object from the RarFile class and try the password on each file in the archive. (or just the first if you know that is encrypted)

```
import rarfile

file = input("Password List Directory: ")
rarFilename = input("Rar File: ")

rf = rarfile.RarFile(rarFilename)
passwordList = open(file,"r")
first_file =  next(rf.infolist)

for i in passwordList:
    password = i.rstrip()        
    try:
        rf.open(first_file, psw=password)
        print(password, "found")
    except rarfile.PasswordRequired:
        print(password,"is not a password")
```

When you open and read lines from a file, the "new line" character is kept 
at the end of the line. This needs to be stripped from each line.

```
for i in passwordList:
    password = i.rstrip()
    try :
        rarfile.read(rarFile, psw=password)
        print('[+] Password Found: '+password)
```

Comment: I changed the code accordingly, but still receive the same output as before.

Comment: The catchall exception handler is hiding the real problem. There is no rarfile.read function.

Comment: After that change, I am getting an error about the object not being subscriptable

Comment: Probably the infolist[0]. Try using next().